# Express app will not start with node app.js

Tags: node.js, express

I was following along to [this tutorial](http://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/) about setting up an express app. But when I ran `node app.js` the server would not start. The previous command that I ran was

```
cd express_example && npm install
```

But I got this error

```
npm WARN engine express@4.9.8: wanted: {"node":">= 0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.8.4","npm":"2.1.4"})
npm WARN engine void-elements@1.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=0.10.0"} (current: {"node":"0.8.4","npm":"2.1.4"})
```

So i thought that it was because a newer version of node was necessary. So I looked at the version of node that I had, noticed it was older so I tried upgrading. But when I ran `brew update node` i got this alert.

```
Error: node-0.10.32 already installed
```

I did some searching around and found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19584407/1120027) here on SO. Which suggested running these commands

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
```

then

```
sudo npm install -g n
```

then

```
sudo n stable
```

But the server still wont startup. But at least I am now at `v0.10.33`

I also found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929563/node-js-express-app-wont-start-listening-on-port-80) on SO whose accepted answer said to try `sudo node app.js` but that just does not seem right, nor did it even work.

Comment: you shouldn't have had problems i just did it, try to do something like this `sudo npm install -g express-generator`

Comment: What is the error when starting the server?

Comment: @BrendanAshworth There is no error, it simply does not start when in the terminal I entered `node app.js`

Comment: @JGallardo what is the response code if you get no response from the command? (`echo $?`) If it is 0, it may not have binded correctly.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Express 4 and using the generator, there is a slightly diffrent method for running the app. Express 4 changed the file structure to:

```
├── app.js
├── bin
│   └── www
├── package.json
├── public
│   ├── images
│   ├── javascripts
│   └── stylesheets
│       └── style.css
├── routes
│   ├── index.js
│   └── users.js
└── views
    ├── error.jade
    ├── index.jade
    └── layout.jade
```

Notice the `bin/www` directory.

The app start logic is now seperated in the `bin/www` file. Therefore you have to run your app with the following command:

```
DEBUG=<<app_name>> ./bin/www
```

**Reference:** http://expressjs.com/starter/generator.html

Comment: I don't know if it has again changed but your command does not work. It says that DEBUG is not a recognized command. Instead it suggest SET DEBUG=app_name & npm start but again the & is not recognized so you should do those separatedly