# How can I run loopback application on port 80

Tags: node.js, express, loopbackjs

I'm using loopback.io which base on expressjs and I tried to add port as the first parameter of `app.listen` like this:

```
// server.js

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(80, function() {
    app.emit('started');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', app.get('url'));
  });
};
```

But it doesn't work.

I have been searching for this for awhile but I haven't found the solution yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `port` property in `server/config.json`. See https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-sandbox/blob/master/server/config.json#L4

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to problems seen in Express; one such answer is here [Node.js + Express: app won't start listening on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929563/node-js-express-app-wont-start-listening-on-port-80)

I don't see it explicitly noted in the documentation, but have also had the issue where listening on port 80 required sudo (root). The loopback.js documentation https://apidocs.strongloop.com/loopback/#app-listen states that your call is just passed to the HTTP Server class https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback but your format also matches that of Express (hence the first link).

Your error message would be helpful in knowing if root access is the problem or if it's something else.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to set the port dynamically so that it would be 3001 in development and 80 in production. This is what worked for me:

```js
app.start = function() {  
  //change the port if needed for production  
  if (process.env.PORT) {  
    app.set('port', process.env.PORT);
  }

  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 80,
  "remoting": {
    "context": false,
    "rest": {
      "normalizeHttpPath": false,
      "xml": false
    },
    "json": {
      "limit": "50mb"
    },
    "urlencoded": {
      "limit": "50mb",
      "extended": true
    },
    "handleErrors": false
  },
  "legacyExplorer": false,
  "logoutSessionsOnSensitiveChanges": true
}
```

Please refer to this `server/config.json` sample.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using loopback x3 you need to create a file called `server/config.local.json`. Then copy all files in `server/config.json` into it. Now, add "your port number" you need  to the "port property" in `server/config.local.json` and it will work.

For detail, see the original source: https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Environment-specific-configuration.html#application-wide-configuration