# LoopBack does not read port property from config.json (or other config files)

Tags: configuration, server, loopbackjs

So I want to run multiple LoopBacks listening different ports (makes dev easier). I can achieve this by using `PORT=808x node .`, but I would prefer a configured alternative.

When I tried to use the configs, I noticed strange behavior. Other configs, such as the `restApiRoot` matches whatever I write for it in the `server/config.json`, but the port is always `8080`, unless I use env variables or such. I checked the documentation for all configuration files LoopBack reads, non of them has new value for `port`. Where does that `port` value come from? How can I force it to use the one in `server/config.json` or in similar official configuration files?

**UPDATE: My server/server.js server/config.json and package.json files**

When I start this with `node .` command, the port variable is `8080` instead of `8082` and when I wget, the response (404) comes from `8080` and `8082` gives no response, as there is no server serving that port.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "external-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "pretest": "jshint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "compression": "^1.0.3",
    "cors": "^2.5.2",
    "loopback": "^2.22.0",
    "loopback-boot": "^2.6.5",
    "loopback-component-explorer": "^2.1.0",
    "loopback-connector-mysql": "^2.4.1",
    "loopback-datasource-juggler": "^2.39.0",
    "serve-favicon": "^2.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.5.6"
  }
}
```

server/server.js

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var boot = require('loopback-boot');

var app = module.exports = loopback();

app.start = function() {
  // start the web server
  return app.listen(function() {
    app.emit('started');
    console.log(app.get('port'))
    var baseUrl = app.get('url').replace(/\/$/, '');
    console.log('Web server listening at: %s', baseUrl);
    if (app.get('loopback-component-explorer')) {
      var explorerPath = app.get('loopback-component-explorer').mountPath;
      console.log('Browse your REST API at %s%s', baseUrl, explorerPath);
    }
  });
};

// Bootstrap the application, configure models, datasources and middleware.
// Sub-apps like REST API are mounted via boot scripts.
boot(app, __dirname, function(err) {
  if (err) throw err;

  // start the server if `$ node server.js`
  if (require.main === module)
    app.start();
});
```

server/config.json

```
{
  "restApiRoot": "/api",
  "host": "0.0.0.0",
  "port": 8082
}
```

Comment: which version of loopback are you using ? it works for me when i change the port in config.json, can you please edit your question with the code of your config.json and server.js and don't forget to mention your loopback version thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, it seems that when I run LoopBack with sudo, the configuration files are applied. Very confusing.

So the command `node .` will lead to wrong port and `sudo node .` will read the port from the `server/config.json`. It seems like other configuration parameters are read correctly, even without `sudo`, for some reason PORT is a special case. There is a [realted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32430773/how-can-i-run-loopback-application-on-port-80#answer-32430893), which shows that this is a NodeJS + Express issue, not a LoopBack issue.