# greenlock (lets'encrypt) with express and port forwarding

Tags: node.js, express, lets-encrypt, greenlock

I am trying to set up letsencrypt (now greenlock apparently) for port forwarding with express.

I had [this first issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929563/node-js-express-app-wont-start-listening-on-port-80) that I solved with:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3443
```

The issue is that, now, I get:

```
Fetching certificate for 'xxx' to use as default for HTTPS server...
[acme-v2] handled(?) rejection as errback:
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1126:14)
Error loading/registering certificate for 'xxx':
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.1.1:80
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1126:14) {
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.1.1',
  port: 80
}
```

My app is like that right now:

```
require("greenlock-express")
    .create({
    server: "https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory",
        email: "xxx@gmail.com", // The email address of the ACME user / hosting provider
        agreeTos: true, // You must accept the ToS as the host which handles the certs
        configDir: "~/.config/acme/", // Writable directory where certs will be saved
        communityMember: true, // Join the community to get notified of important updates
        telemetry: true, // Contribute telemetry data to the projec
    store: require('greenlock-store-fs'),
    approveDomains: ['xxx.xxx.xxx'],
        // Using your express app:
        // simply export it as-is, then include it here
        app: require("../app.js")

        //, debug: true
    })
    .listen(3000, 3443);
```

Apparently I cannot use ports 80 and 443 with nodeJS, but I cannot either use any other port with greenlock... What is the workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm the author of Greenlock.

## Let's Encrypt vs Greenlock

Let's Encrypt is a brand name of the EFF for their Free SSL service.

Greenlock is the brand name I use for my JavaScript client to their service.

I changed the name when they began pursuing a trademark for Let's Encrypt.

## Video Tuts

If you follow the Greenlock QuickStart, you cannot fail. :)

- [Free SSL with Greenlock (Let's Encrypt v2 for Node.js) - Part 1 (QuickStart)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8vaR4CEZ5s)

Also, an oldie, but a goodie:

- [The 15-Minute Guide to Secure VPS Access (for the Paranoid)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YZzhIIJmlE0)

## Keep It Stupid-Simple

- VPS
- netcap
- systemd

On a normal VPS (such as **Digital Ocean**, **Linode**, **Vultr**, or **Scaleway**), where the disk is persistent, use "netcap". This will allow a non-root user to bind to privileged ports:

```sh
sudo setcap 'cap_net_bind_service=+ep' $(which node)
```

TADA! Now you can run `node ./server.js --port 80` as a normal user!

*Aside*:

You can also use `systemd` to stop and start your service. Since `systemd` is sometimes a p.i.t.a., I wrote a [wrapper script in Go](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/serviceman) that makes it really easy to deploy node projects:

```sh
# Install
curl https://rootprojects.org/serviceman/dist/linux/amd64/serviceman -o serviceman
chmod +x ./serviceman
sudo serviceman /usr/local/bin
```

```sh
# Use
cd ./my/node/project
sudo serviceman --username $(whoami) --cap-net-bind add npm start
```

or, if your server isn't called 'server.js' (de facto standard), or extra options:

```sh
cd ./my/node/project
sudo serviceman --username $(whoami) --cap-net-bind add node ./my-server-thing.js -- --my-options
```

All that does is create your `systemd` file for you with sane defaults. I'd recommend you check out the `systemd` documentation as well, but it is a bit hard to grok and there are probably more confusing and otherwise bad tutorials than there are simple and otherwise good tutorials.

## Don't use AWS / EC2 unless you're an expert

I responded to that question you mentioned:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/58388665/151312

It'll probably get a bunch of downvotes from AWS die-hards... but:

Don't use AWS. Use a VPS.

I really like **Digital Ocean** and **Vultr**.

Also, there are Greenlock DNS-01 plugins for both of those. That will make your life real easy.

## HTTP-01 vs DNS-01 validation

The default validations for Greenlock **MUST** go over HTTP on port 80. That's part of the spec. They **CANNOT** go over HTTPS, or over any other port.

However, if you need SSL / TLS for **private networking** (which is probably not your issue), you can use DNS-01 plugins. As mentioned above, it's really simple to integrate with Digital Ocean, Vultr, and a number of others:

- [acme-dns-01-digitalocean](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/acme-dns-01-digitalocean.js)
- [acme-dns-01-vultr](https://git.rootprojects.org/root/acme-dns-01-vultr.js)

There are about a dozen different plugins. You don't *have* to use them except for **wildcard domains** and private networking, but if you think managing the DNS and your VPS in the same place would be a benefit to you, I highly recommend using DNS-01 instead of HTTP-01.

## Port forwarding is a no go

Don't port-forward unless you're an expert and you know what you're doing and why. You're gonna have a hard time and things aren't going to work as you expect.

How do you become an expert... lots of ways (and it's not *hard*)... but, as I understand it,  it isn't really going to help you achieve your most immediate goal.

Sorry I can't be more helpful than that, but it's a big topic.

Comment: Oh my, that's definetely more than useful. If I had this kind of answer each time I asked a question here, I think, my developer life would be a ride on a unicorn under a warm sun and a double rainbow ;)

Comment: Hum... I tried to follow your hint, but I still face this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58392698/express-demo-node-server-not-receiving-any-request-on-port-80

Comment: @Sharcoux did you read the paragraph called "Port forwarding is a no go"?