# iptables Not Forwarding Port as Expected

Tags: express, amazon-ec2, iptables

I'm trying to get a basic Express application running on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu Linux instance.

On such systems, the server has to be run as a super user to listen to port `80`. But that would be a bad practice, so instead you're supposed to listen to a different port (eg. `3000`) and redirect traffic from port `80` to `3000`.

To forward the port I tried using this command from another Stack Overflow answer, [Node.js + Express: app won't start listening on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7929563/node-js-express-app-wont-start-listening-on-port-80)):

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 3000
```

I've run that command (and re-run it to be sure), but even so it doesn't seem to be forwarding `3000` to `80`, because I can only access my server on port `3000`:

```
curl localhost:3000
*html*

curl localhost
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80 after 0 ms: Connection refused
```

I have no idea what I did wrong, but I know nothing about `iptables`, so any help would be appreciated.

P.S. I've tried checking the `iptables` records with the command `sudo iptables -L -n -v`, but the results don't say anything about ports (and again, I don't know `iptables`), so I'm not sure if it's saying my command worked or not:

> Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes target
> prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes target
> prot opt in     out     source               destination
>
> Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)  pkts bytes target
> prot opt in     out     source               destination

Comment: From the iptables tag: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Did you save the rules using iptables-save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your test doesn't work is because trying to access the service from localhost bypasses the NAT table. You need to test from a different host. It should then work presuming the rule is loaded correctly and there is no firewall or other rules interfering.

Note, there are multiple other, probably better ways, to get get a non-privileged process bound to a privileged port. There is a big discussion in [Is there a way for non-root processes to bind to "privileged" ports on Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux) which includes the solution your using among others.

Comment: From the iptables tag: IPTABLES SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Support questions may be asked on https://superuser.com. Use this tag only for questions on programming with iptables. Questions about configuring iptables should be asked on Server Fault (https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: This comment saves my day, should test externally!!! THANKS!